# PCAP file and routing to its destination

Tags: pcap

I am new to PCAP file format. Does the file have the routing information regarding the routing from the src ip to the destination ip?

I am to know if routing is going through a specific route and how often?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the file have the routing information regarding the routing from the src ip to the destination ip?

Not in general.

The file has packets taken directly from the network, so, for example, if you captured an IP packet on an Ethernet, it would have the Ethernet source and destination addresses, which are the Ethernet address of the machine that sent the packet on that network and the Ethernet address of the machine on that network to which it was sent, and the IP source and destination addresses, which are the IP address of the machine that originally sent the packet and the IP address of the machine to which the packet is ultimately being sent.

The Ethernet addresses give the source and destination of one *particular* routing hop; the other routing hop information is *not*, in general, available.

The only way in which you'd have *some* routing information would be if the IPv4 header had the "record route" option, in which case each host that routed the packet would add its IP address to the list of IP addresses in that option.  However, packets only *very* rarely have that option (and you'd probably have to modify the program sending the packet in order for it to have that option!) and, if the packet *does* have that option, it will only show the hosts through which the packet has already been routed, not the hosts through which the packet will next be routed on the path to the destination host.

If you want to know the routing path from a given IP address to another IP address, you'd need to use the `traceroute` command on UN*X, or the `tracert` command on Windows, on the source host, and hope that it works (the packets it sends might not cause the appropriate ICMP Time Exceeded Message message to be send back; `traceroute` and `tracert` depend on it being sent).

Comment: Can i try to ask again, Is there some way to figure out the route to a URL/ Destination. So if i am implementing it in a Graph DB. I would only have src ip and dest ip. or more information on what's happening on the way? to see a route to a destination?

Comment: You're now asking a different question.  If you want to find the route to an IP address, I've already answered that question in the last paragraph of my answer - use `traceroute`/`tracert`, or implement what it does yourself (`traceroute` is open source).

Comment: I know about traceroute, thanks. I am trying to understand if there is some out-of-the-box way to figuring it out just from the data in PCAP file. Maybe not the whole route, just a part of it ???

Comment: As my answer says, there is *NOT* a general way of figuring it out just from the data in a pcap file.  The only part of the route you can get is the hop that goes over the link on which you captured traffic.